# Typescript: Specifying a type for an instance method

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript 3.3.
There is a `type` from a library: `type Fn = (arg0: t1...) => any`,
and I imported it, want to use it to sign an instance method:

```js
class A {
  mtd() {} // to be signed
}
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to reuse the type signature of `Fn` in order to avoid repetition, you can do that, but the method will depend on whether `mtd` must be a proper method or an arrow function assigned to a class property.

> Class methods and function properties are not the same. They differ in terms of handling `this`, which makes property functions incompatible with inheritance. Proceed with caution.

**Class method**

```
type Fn = (argument: string) => any;

interface IA {
  mtd: Fn;
}

class A implements IA {
  /**
   * Parameter types must be repeated  but they will be type-checked as expected.
   */
  mtd(argument: string) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

**Arrow function property**

```
type Fn = (argument: string) => any;

class A {
  /**
   * We know `argument` is a `string.
   */
  mtd: Fn = argument => {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer changes the method on the class prototype to a separate function-valued property on each instance... and as an arrow function it also loses the `this` context. That might be acceptable, but the difference should probably be noted.

Comment: @jcalz you're right, the difference should be made explicit. I have updated my answer. Thank you for noticing that.